One type for multiple generic arguments
Angular's matDialog.open() is generic and can take three arguments. matDialog.open<Type, Data, Return>.
My dialog has custom types like so MyDialogType<T>, MyDialogData<T> and MyDialogReturn<T>.
Writing this out in full results in something like this.
this.matDialog.open<MyDialogType<Boat>, MyDialogData<Boat>, MyDialogReturn<Boat>>()

So I am curious if it's possible to have just one type for all those. I.e.
this.matDialog.open<OneType<Boat>>()


Is this about angular? If so, please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] so that the code doesn't depend on it; it should be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and get to work immediately, without having to debug our way to the starting line. Right now, this isn't anything that has a matDialog in a standalone IDE, so we are immediately hit having to re-create or find and import the types you're talking about.


Create a type with a generic member as shown below

type OneType<T> = MyDialogType<T> & MyDialogData<T> & MyDialogReturn<T>;


Define Boat

type Boat = {
    material: string;
    poweredBy: string;
}


Use OneType<T> with Boat

type BoatTest = OneType<Boat>

Here's a full ts playground demo to try out my solution.
